# Error opening qgis_dev 3.9.0-55

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I've installed qgis_dev 3.9.0-55 through the OSGEOW64 installer on my win7 machine. I've got the error message proj_6_2.dll is missing (qgis_dev with grass) or "could not load qgis_app.dll" (qgis-dev without grass). I've uninstalled all and reinstalled it, but always the same...any hints?

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to execute it? Did you try from the `qgis.bat` file in the directory or typing `qgis` in the OSGeo4W shell?

Comment: I've just started it like other win programms - see picture added

Comment: exact same issue. If it's useful 3.8 works when updated using the same process.

Comment: Thanks George, yes 3.8 works for me too using the same process...may be it's a build error of the nightly version

Comment: same issue on Windows 10, bad nightly I think